# Redirect example.com/out/1234 to another URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know theres a lot of posts about redirects but this is a little different (I think).

Basically I want my outlinks to be example.com/out/1234 and I want them to go to a php that looks up the URL 1234 if referenced to in MySQL and the php header redirect to that URL.

The problem Im having is passing 1234 to a page. I know how if it was out.php?q=1234 but I want it to be /out/1234

Does there need to be an index file within an /out directory that also has a htaccess to rewrite it?

If so, any ideas what the regex need to be to do this? I have seen a few sites doing this and I cant work it out.

Comment: how does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the tag-wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info or the Apache manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html and its examples? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htaccess file in your document root, you can try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?out/(.*)$ /out.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Replace the `/out.php` with whereever your php script for handling the URL is

Comment: +1 but lose the forward-slash and question mark in the pattern. Path matching in `.htaccess` files starts at the current dir. I'd also add the `QSA` flag, just in case

Comment: @Phil I add those because sometimes the OP moves the rules into server/vhost config (for some reason this happens even if the question pertains to htaccess) and it isn't until a long string of comments before it's revealed that the rules actually ended up in vhost config. So I put those there just in case, in htaccess (Apache 2.0+ at least), they're not needed.

Comment: Hi Jon,

Thanks for helping me out, really appreciate it.

I have tried your code but it doesnt appear to work:

I have created a PHP file that echos this: `<?php echo $_GET["q"]; ?>`


However, if I create a link like this: `<a href="/out/1234567890">click to send variable</a>` , it just links to a 404.

Comment: @Phil Hi phil, what does the QSA flag do? Do I just add [QSA] to the end?

Comment: @MikeMeade your php file is at `/out.php`? And when you go to `/out.php?q=123456789`, it works? Is there a directory `/out`? `QSA` means "query string append", so whatever query string you may have gets appended to the end

Comment: @JonLin , yes the php file is `/out.php`. Yes `/out.php?q=123456789` works fine. there is no `/out` directory. So do I need to use the `QSA` thing then to make it work? thanks

Comment: @JonLin if I add the QSA flag like this `RewriteRule ^/?out/(.*)$ /out.php?q=$1 [L, QSA]` I get a 500 error.

Comment: @JonLin Ok I have found the problem, I have this in my htaccess which is causing the problem, as a default Magento Installation.  `RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]` . Any ideas what that does, and if I would need it?

Comment: @JonLin If I take out the `RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]` it breaks all other pages on my site.

Comment: @MikeMeade You can't have spaces inside the square brackets. Spaces are used to separate directive parameters. I don't know anything about the magento rules or how it works.